# Php query for loop does not work as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php script that query a mysql database in order to send a message. I want to send the "message" variable in loops every 1000 rows of the database table. Below is the code, what is wrong with this?

```
<?php
    $num = $con->query("SELECT gcm_regid from gcm_users")->rowCount();
    $current_num = 0;
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num / 999; $i++) {
        $query = $con->query("SELECT gcm_regid from gcm_users LIMIT $current_num, 999");
        foreach ($query as $data) {
            $row[] = $data["gcm_regid"];
        }
        $pushStatus = send_notification($con, $row, $message);
        $current_num += 999;
    }
?>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yLff8n5d/

Comment: so whats going on with above code?

Comment: the error is that the loop does not execute every 1000 rows as I want to

Comment: This code makes absolutely no sense. Did you take this from a tutorial site or what? Also, what the hell is jsfiddle supposed to help us with?

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
<?php
    $num = $con->query("SELECT gcm_regid from gcm_users")->rowCount();
    $current_num = 0;
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num / 999; $i++) {
        $query = $con->query("SELECT gcm_regid from gcm_users LIMIT $current_num, 999");
        $row = array()
        while($result = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            $row[] = $result['gcm_regid']
        }
        $pushStatus = send_notification($con, $row, $message);
        $current_num += 999;
    }
?>
```

Comment: So I will have to incorporate a while loop like the fiddle example below? Can you please have a quick check? http://jsfiddle.net/yLff8n5d/1

Comment: i commented bellow

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_assoc(). I tried fetch_assoc(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) too, same error.